# Texturing a tree

Tags: texturing

I am making a 3d model of a tree using the sappling add on, when i put the bark texture on the tree the texture looks stretched (ive tried use UV for mapping and auto texture space).

Comment: Hi, maybe adding some screenshot or sharing the .blend will help some one understand your problem better...